# Center Gradient

Tags: html, css, gradient

I created a gradient with the colors white, red, white like this:

```
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, white , red, white);
background: -o-linear-gradient(right, white, red, white);
background: -moz-linear-gradient(right, white, red, white); 
background: linear-gradient(to right, white , red, white);
```

Here you can see the demo: http://jsfiddle.net/mmMVN/43/

What I wanted to achieve then was that the:

1.**White** Color goes until **30%** of the box

2.**Red** from **30-70%** of the box

3 and then  **White** again for the rest **30%** of the box.

**Means that the red part is in exactly in the middle of the box**

So what I did was:

```
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, white 30%, red 70%, white 100%); /* For Safari 5.1 to 6.0 */
background: -o-linear-gradient(right, white 30%, red 70%, white 100%); /* For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(right, white 30%, red 70%, white 100%); /* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
background: linear-gradient(to right, white 30%, red 70%, white 100%); /* Standard syntax (must be last) */
```

But this doesn't center the **red** part, it moved it to the right part.Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/mmMVN/41/

**How can I center the red part?** Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might try this:

```css
#grad1 {
    height: 200px;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, white 30%, red 50%, white 70%); 
    background: -o-linear-gradient(right, white 30%, red 50%, white 70%); 
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(right, white 30%, red 50%, white 70%); 
    background: linear-gradient(to right, white 30%, red 50%, white 70%);
}
```

```html
<div id="grad1"></div>
```

The issue is coming from you percentage repartition:

```
right, white 30%, red 70%, white 100%
```

meant that the white will start at 30%, the red will be full at 70% then fade to full white at 100%

---

Update after OP comment:

```css
#bck {
    height: 200px;
    background: red;
    margin-left: 30%;
    width: 40%;
}
```

```html
<div id="bck"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Can You maybe add to you answer how I can disabe the blur between the colors? Or reduce it! Thanks

Comment: @JohnSmith do you want to fully disable blur?

Comment: @JohnSmith the gradient *is* using blur

Comment: Yes I would like to reduce the blur! Or remove the blur completley

Comment: @JohnSmith, you want a centered red background ?

Comment: Yes! I thought gradient is the easiest way

Comment: @Thomas Thank you really! perfect but in my case its not good for me to use the margin! IS the same effect not possible with gradients? I will mark your answer as correct!

Comment: @JohnSmith Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74095/discussion-between-thomas-and-john-smith).

Answer (score 0):

The solution is:

```
   background: linear-gradient(to right,  white 30% , red 50% , white 70%)
```

See the demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/mmMVN/47/
Used the border so it's like more visible

Answer (score 0):

Try putting like this:

```
#grad1 {
    height: 200px;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, white 30%, red 31%, red 69%, white 70%); 
    background: -o-linear-gradient(right, white 30%, red 31%, red 69%, white 70%); 
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(right, white 30%, red 31%, red 69%, white 70%); 
    background: linear-gradient(to right, white 30%, red 31%, red 69%, white 70%);
}
```

Hope this helps. Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mmMVN/49/).

Comment: You should use the snippet tool :)